# Classification of non-complete dvr's

Tags: abstract-algebra, valuation-theory

I would like to know if there are any results similar to Cohen`s classification of complete dvr's if we drop the completeness assumption. 
Take an equal characteristic discrete valuation ring $A$ with residue field $k$. When does follows that $A\cong k(t)$ ?
I am aware of the counterexample [A conjectural characterization of equal characteristic DVRs](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3213372/a-conjectural-characterization-of-equal-characteristic-dvrs/3213581). I am asking about assumptions we can ask for to ensure this result. What about $A$ of characteristic $0$ or $k$ algebraically closed?